# Ruby 1.9.3 installation failed in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

(OS: Windows 7)

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

While i am trying to install ruby with rvm in cygwin i got below error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Mu7r6l8/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p448'
make[1]: exts.mk: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'exts.mk'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Mu7r6l8/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p448'
uncommon.mk:178: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Due to that i am not able to proceed with the Ruby installation in Cygwin.

Comment: If you want to install Ruby for Cygwin, you should do so with the Cygwin `ruby` package via `setup.exe`.

Comment: I know that. I tried that option. But as per my project settings i need to use RVM to install ruby. Can you help me on that

Comment: The Cygwin Ruby package includes specific build instructions and a few patches, all available [here](http://cygwin-ports.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=cygwin-ports/ruby;a=tree).  Not being familiar with RVM, I'm not sure if these can be incorporated therein; I'm afraid we don't support building Ruby any other way.

Comment: FYI everyone interested. Tried to compile Ruby 2.1.5 via `rbenv-install`. After some time compiling it failed with a message:

```
compiling rat.c
installing default rational libraries
printf.c:31:1: error: conflicting types for ‘utoa’
 utoa(char *p, char *e, unsigned int x)
 ^
```

I suppose making it compile well will take enormous effort so I'm sticking to a ported version (2.0.0 to the date), as Yaakov suggests.